# Lacking motivation

Tags: phd, research-process, graduate-school, funding, motivation

I am a student pursuing a Ph.D. I am just an average student who is hard-working enough to complete the assignments and tasks on time.
I have been feeling incompetent for the last so many months. I am not even focusing on a particular work. There is n support from my supervisor and he is found out to be very much manipulative. The working environment is equally not supportive. I have been feeling stuck for more than a year now but can't leave the program. But, in the back of my mind, there is an urge to leave the program. I am worried about my future as I belong to the reputed institute. It is affecting my mental as well as physical health.

Please help me out.

Comment: You should try and talk to a professional about your mental health, but a good first step would be searching "impostor syndrome". Can you change supervisors?

Comment: Can you indicating a location and scientific field? Where I am at, PhD students don't get assignments.